# Set MinimumSize according the controls residing inside form

Tags: c#, winforms

Title of my question could be make it look like a duplicate but please read ahead as my problem is a bit different.

I am trying to replicate the minimum size functionality of some popular media players like MPC-HC or VLC where when you try to make it small the minimum size it achieves is when only MenuStrip and Player Controls are visible.

The code I've written to attain this is:

```
public NewMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    int ClientTop = RectangleToScreen(ClientRectangle).Top;
    int height = menuStrip1.Height + panel1.Height + ClientTop - Top;
    label4.Text = height.ToString();
    MinimumSize = new Size(373, height);
}
```

The problem is that when it runs, its not working perfectly and the `menuStrip1` is still getting blocked a little at bottom from the `panel1` (Docked at bottom) where the player controls will be placed.

Below is the Image of what I was able to attain with above code.

[image: What I'm getting as an output]

Next Image is what I expected:

[image]

Note that label on left updates when resize the form and the label on the right is the determined height via code.

My Idea was to add the difference of `Form`'s `Top` and the `Top` of total rectangle visible on the screen i.e. the height of the title bar otherwise the resulting height will be even smaller and hide the `menuStrip1` completely. I don't want to hardcode any values because it'll make the interface less adaptable to the changes that I might be doing later on.

Comment: Appcompat in Win10 to hide the effects of its really fat borders defeat this code.  Keep it relative to avoid trouble: int height = this.Height - (panel1.Top - menuStrip1.Bottom);

Comment: @HansPassant Hey it really worked! Thanks alot! Can you please post the same as an answer so I can mark it. Also, can you suggest where can I read more about relative user interface and AppCompat as I'm yet confused how it worked and mine did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correctly determine the minimum height in this case is to keep the calculations relative which can be attained by:

```
int height = Height - (panel1.Top - menuStrip1.Bottom);
```

All credit goes to Hans Passant who provided this code. I'm just posting it as an answer to mark my question solved. Thank you.